# Looping through StackPanel children in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I have a `StackPanel` that is full of controls, I am trying to loop through the elements and get their Names, but it seems that I need to cast each element to its type in order to access its `Name` property.

But what if I have a lot of different types in the StackPanel and I just want to get the elements name?

Is there a better way to do that?

Here is what I've tried:

```
foreach (object child in tab.Children)
{
    UnregisterName(child.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It should be enough to cast to the right base class. 
Everything that descends from `FrameworkElement` has a Name property.

```
foreach(object child in tab.Children)
{
   string childname = null;
   if (child is FrameworkElement )
   {
     childname = (child as FrameworkElement).Name;
   }

   if (childname != null)
      ...

}
```

Comment: How about `childname = (child as FrameworkElement)?.Name;`?

Comment: This is an answer from 2013, no `?.` yet. I'm not going to retrofit that everywhere. And I'm not sure if it's always better, here `((FrameworkElement)child).Name` might be the most optimized form.

Comment: Yeah, I figured since you were editing the answer anyways. I saw the date.

Answer (score 9):

You may just use the appropriate type for the foreach loop variable:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement element in panel.Children)
{
    var name = element.Name;
}
```

This works as long as there are only `FrameworkElement` derived controls in the Panel. If there are also others (like derived from `UIElement` only) you may write this:

```
using System.Linq;
...
foreach (var element in panel.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
{
    var name = element.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
foreach(var child in tab.Children.OfType<Control>)
{
    UnregisterName(child.Name);
}
```