Replicates of a User Control with a TextBox Element and How to Keep Different Texts Saved When Application Is Closed and Opened Again
Here are the steps to the problem I am facing that I can't figure out. I am new to C# and WPF. I am using WPF .NET framework in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9.4.

I created a User Control that contains 3 elements (A button, A checkBox, and a TextBox)
I added this user control 8 times in my main window xaml file using stackPanel,
At runtime, each time I type something in one of the text boxes, and hit the button, it does something (It works)

**But the problem is now I have different texts in all 8 textboxes, and I need to have them saved and shown up next time I run the application again. Can you help me with this?
**
Thanks,
DEAN
I tried to access each usercontrol giving them a name, but I can't reach the individual textboxes for each replicate of usercontrol.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

hey dean! as the community bot already said, having some code samples makes it way easier for others to help. :)

Multiple controls of the same type are easily handled by an ItemsControl. See also Data Templating Overview. The ItemsSource property would hold a collection of data items. There are many ways to save and load this data. Please be more specific.

As of the very basic description , I assume that you are not using a View Model . Please try following the MVVM concept that includes View Model and Binding from the XAML to your View Model class.

The UC's are "children" of the StackPanel's .Children collection that you can iterate over. The UC's have a "relative" position in the StackPanel. You can use that as the (virtual) "identifier" for the 8 text "strings" when loading / unloading (e.g. string 1 goes in UC 1; etc.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990735/looping-through-stackpanel-children-in-wpf (You need a "public" accessor on the TextBox in your UC to get at the .Text property; e.g. public TextBox MyTb => this.UxTB)
